# Textbox has text in it, but text property = ""; VISUAL STUDIOS WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

My textbox element looks like this:

`<TextBox x:Name="NameTextbox" Style="{DynamicResource Button_No_Light_TextBox_Black}" TabIndex="0"/>`

The styling for the text box is this:

```
        <Setter Property="Text" Value=""/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <TextBox Padding="15,0,0,0" FontFamily="Sitka Small" Height="50" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Background="Black" Foreground="Red" BorderBrush="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,0,0,0" FontSize="20" TextWrapping="Wrap"  BorderThickness="0" Width="640">
                        <TextBox.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBox.Resources>
                    </TextBox>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

In my CS file, I have written

```
 private void Create_Account_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string name = NameTextbox.Text;
            string email = EmailTextbox.Text;
            string password = PasswordGrid.pb.Password;
            Account newAccount = new Account(name, email, password);   
        };
```

but *name* is equal to "".

The same applies to email.

[Image of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0HMz.png)

Comment: You style it with empty string, it is in the very first line of code you provided `<Setter Property="Text" Value=""/>`

Comment: You should also not have a TextBox in the Template of a TextBox. There should be `<ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>`. Not sure if you need to set the Template at all. You may move the Triggers to `<Style.Triggers>` and the Border Style to `<Style.Resources>`.

Comment: @xdjiijii But even if this is removed, why does the text property value remain empty when text is added to the text box?

Comment: Because you are typing into the inner TextBox, which has nothing to do with the outer, styled TextBox. Be aware that you have two TextBoxes!

Comment: try using a data context and binding instead of code behind

Comment: @NigelBess What does that have to do with the problem? Please do not add more confusion.